# require_tree argument must be a directory in a Rails 5 upgraded app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I just upgraded my app from `Rails 4.2.7` to `Rails 5.0.0.1`. I used [RailsDiff](http://railsdiff.org/4.2.7/5.0.0.1) to make sure I had everything covered and I believe I did. So far everything has worked well up until the loading of my app.

Now I am seeing this error:

```
Sprockets::ArgumentError at /
require_tree argument must be a directory
```

This is my `application.css`:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope. *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

This is my `application.js`

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This is what the server log looks like:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-09-02 09:08:19 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Processing by ProfilesController#index as HTML
  Rendering profiles/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Profile Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles"
  Rendered profiles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (45.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 367ms (ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)


DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from initialize at /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@myapp/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/raised_exception.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from initialize at /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1myapp/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/raised_exception.rb:8)

Sprockets::ArgumentError - require_tree argument must be a directory:
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:182:in `rescue in block in process_directives'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:179:in `block in process_directives'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
```

I am using no plugins of any kind. It is a fairly simple/vanilla app. The only styling is from the default `scaffold.scss`.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I finally figured it out. So because I am doing the upgrade, RailsDiff didn't tell me that I was missing something.

So the error message wasn't incorrect, however, what I forgot to do was to create an empty directory.

In my `app/assets/javascripts/cable.js`, I had the following:

```
//= require_tree ./channels
```

However, I forgot to actually create that folder.

So to fix this, all I had to do was create an empty folder within `app/assets/javascripts` called `channels`. Also, because git ignores empty directories, within that newly created folder, I also had to create an empty file called `.keep`.

So once I did the following, everything worked like a charm:

- Create folder: `app/assets/javascripts/channels`
- Create empty file within that folder: `app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep`

Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: Still working in 2018 - thanks for posting this - worked for me!

Comment: In my case, I converted from javascript sprockets to webpacker and I forgot to remove a line referencing the old javascript location in app/assets/config/manifest.js

Comment: Still working in 2021, I was upgrading from Rails `4.2.11.1` to Rails `5.0.1`. Thanks for the clarification. The error in the console was wrong as you mentioned.

Comment: thanks man, save my time

Comment: In my case, a javascript file was looking for files in my (empty) vendor folder, which I had dockerignored by mistake

Answer (score 7):

Faced a similar, but not the same issue. During upgrade of Rails from 5.2.3 to 5.2.4.1

`$ rails s` returned:

```
Expected to find a manifest file in `app/assets/config/manifest.js` (Sprockets::Railtie::ManifestNeededError)
But did not, please create this file and use it to link any assets that need to be rendered by your app:

Example:
  //= link_tree ../images
  //= link_directory ../javascripts .js
  //= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
and restart your server
```

Ok, followed the instructions, created `manifest.js` with the above content, then

`$ rails s` returned:

```
Sprockets::ArgumentError at / link_tree argument must be a directory
```

Fix:

create empty `.keep` file in a new `images` folder (which was possibly deleted at some point in the past without any immediate consequences):

`app/assets/images/.keep`

Answer (score 6):

The problem occurs when using `rails new appname --skip-keeps` flag - it still tries to require non-existing files and generally is a mistake on Rails team side.

This is just a different approach to the described problem, the main solution works perfectly;

1. Open `app/assets/javascripts/cable.js`
2. Remove autogenerated `//= require_tree ./channels`, from line 6

Keep your codebase as small as possible, someone skipped the `.keep`s for a reason.

Comment: I agree with keeping codebase as small as possible. I had the issue when I upgraded rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ActionCable
then removed all content inside `app/assets/javascripts/cable.js`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too because I have messed with my app files. I first created it locally and then uploaded the files to my GitHub repo and then cloned it to the original location after removing local files. That made some directories in the `assets directory` and vendor directory missing.

What I have done is recreate them related to the `manifest.js` path.

so since `manifest.js` path is `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

eg:

```
//= link_tree ../images
```

create ***images*** directory inside ***assets*** directory

```
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
```

create ***vendor*** directory outside ***app*** directory and create ***javascript*** directory inside ***vendor*** directory