# rails 6 webpacker in production: rake assets:precompile fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have a typical rails 6.0.2 app set up on a production server and I'm using git hooks to deploy the app.  When I try to run: `rails assets:precompile` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::ArgumentError: link_directory argument must be a directory
/home/user/myapp/app/assets/config/manifest.js:2
```

Here is the manifest.js file

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

I cant figure out what Im doing wrong.  Unless I'm mistaken, doesn't webpacker replace sprockets?

Comment: Can you paste manifest.js code with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `manifest.js`, your error tells that in `manifest.js` line 2, `link_directory` argument must be a directory, and not a file. It should probably look like this

```
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

If you notice there is gap between `stylesheets` and `.css`, it means that link all the `css` files from `stylesheets` directory, there must be some formatting problem in your code. Fix it and it should work!

Comment: thanks for your help.  I've updated my question with the code from my manifest.js file.  Im not sure what you mean by 'formatting problem' can you give me some more info?

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else who got this error, I simply added a directory in `assets`, called `stylesheets`, and added a file `.keep` within it.  That fixed my problem.

Comment: This did it for me after I moved stylesheets un the js/packs folder for webpacker to work properly

Comment: I created app/images/.keep (since in my case it was failing for static assets, not css).

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `.keep` file in both the `images` and `javascript` folders fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

double check all the asset folder for an empt `.keep` file

common culprit could be images folder

this post may also help out

[require_tree argument must be a directory in a Rails 5 upgraded app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294859/require-tree-argument-must-be-a-directory-in-a-rails-5-upgraded-app)